# Styling the button of a filefield xtype

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4

I am building a web application and the user is allowed to upload a photo using a `fileField`. I am trying to style the button, however, nothing I try seems to work. At first I tried using the element inspector to look for the proper class type but that did not give the results I wanted. Next, I assigned a class to the fileField and created a css for that style but it did not work either. Here is my code:

my filefield

```
{

    xtype: 'filefield',
    x: 200,
    y: 910,
    cls: 'fileBtnClass',
    width: 200,
    fieldLabel: 'LABEL',
    hideLabel: true,
    labelStyle: 'text-align: center; color: white',
    labelWidth: 140,
    buttonOnly: true,
    buttonText: 'Browse'

}
```

my css:

```
.fileBtnClass {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    font-family: 'Arial' !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    color: black !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What happens is that the button size gets larger to accommodate the text. However, the text itself does not get larger in any way.

Styling certain fields in ExtJS proves to be a pinch at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Ext.form.field.File](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File) has a [`buttonConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-buttonConfig) property which expect a [Ext.button.Button](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.button.Button) configuration. If you filter for *Cls* within the button API you get at least 10 Cls properties that can all be used to style the button.

> `arrowCls` : **String**
>
> *The className used for the inner arrow element if the button has a menu. ...*
>
> `baseCls` : **String**
>
> *The base CSS class to add to all buttons. ...*
>
> `cls` : **String**
>
> *A CSS class string to apply to the button's main element.*
>
> `componentCls` : **String**
>
> *CSS Class to be added to a components root level element to give distinction to it via styling.*
>
> `disabledCls` : **String**
>
> *CSS class to add when the Component is disabled. ...*
>
> `focusCls` : **String**
>
> *The CSS class to add to a button when it is in the focussed state. ...*
>
> `iconCls` : **String**
>
> *A css class which sets a background image to be used as the icon for this button. ...*
>
> `menuActiveCls` : **String**
>
> *The CSS class to add to a button when it's menu is active. ...*
>
> `overCls` : **String**
>
> *The CSS class to add to a button when it  is in the over (hovered) state. ...*
>
> `pressedCls` : **String**
>
> *The CSS class to add to a button when it is in the pressed state. ...*

---

**Additional Info**

---

*`cls` -> the additional one*

This class is added to the inner element of the button

---

*`baseCls` -> the one who change it all*

```
// following the template that is used to render a button
    '<span id="{id}-btnWrap" role="presentation" class="{baseCls}-wrap',
        '<tpl if="splitCls"> {splitCls}</tpl>',
        '{childElCls}" unselectable="on">',
        '<span id="{id}-btnEl" class="{baseCls}-button" role="presentation">',
            '<span id="{id}-btnInnerEl" class="{baseCls}-inner {innerCls}',
                '{childElCls}" unselectable="on">',
                '{text}',
            '</span>',
            '<span role="presentation" id="{id}-btnIconEl" class="{baseCls}-icon-el {iconCls}',
                '{childElCls} {glyphCls}" unselectable="on" style="',
                '<tpl if="iconUrl">background-image:url({iconUrl});</tpl>',
                '<tpl if="glyph && glyphFontFamily">font-family:{glyphFontFamily};</tpl>">',
                '<tpl if="glyph">&#{glyph};</tpl><tpl if="iconCls || iconUrl">&#160;</tpl>',
            '</span>',
        '</span>',
    '</span>',
    // if "closable" (tab) add a close element icon
    '<tpl if="closable">',
        '<span id="{id}-closeEl" role="presentation"',
            ' class="{baseCls}-close-btn"',
            '<tpl if="closeText">',
                ' title="{closeText}" aria-label="{closeText}"',
            '</tpl>',
            '>',
        '</span>',
    '</tpl>'
```

The classes that are directly affected by baseCls:

```
// applied in the template
{baseCls}-wrap
{baseCls}-button
{baseCls}-inner
{baseCls}-close-btn
// just a view that are (may be) applied in code
{glyphCls}
{innerCls}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the `baseCls`property.

Comment: For some weird reason, the width and height properties are not followed. I tried placing it in the buttonConfig and in my css but nothing worked.

Comment: @Razgriz You're welcome! Please see my edit for some more information concerning the classes

Comment: @Razgriz You should use chrome developer tools / IE developer tools / Firebug here. I guess the Field, which wrap the button may cause a `overflow: hidden`. If not take a look at my additional info first and use one of the developer tools to find the css element which overrides your porperties